# Как правильно экранировать фигурные скобки

Tags: php

Есть какая-то переменная `$var` равная например 123. Я хочу получить ее значение в таком виде: `${123}`. Строкой, но в фигурных скобках и с долларом. Как мне это сделать? Если экранировать все "неясные" символы вот так `"\$\{$var\}"` то выходит не то `$\{123\}`. Можно конечно воспользоваться `sprintf` вместо строковой интерполяции...

Comment: дак доллар только экранируйте, скобки то зачем? или конкатенацию пользуйте

Comment: @teran если я не экранирую скобки то они исчезают. Т.е. получается просто `$123`.

Comment: двойную скобку тогда

Comment: @teran а вот это уже верно. Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратитесь к документации по строкам: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php

- чтобы экранировать знак доллара, используйте `\$`
- далее пишите по две фигурных скобки `{{` и `}}`. Первая и последние скобки будут просто выводится как символы, а вот внутренние будут относится к последующей переменной, то есть `{$var}`. Фактически экранирования тут нет, просто вложенные скобки рассматриваются вместе с переменной, которая в них заключена.

Как вы уже написали, возможны варианты, используя `sprintf` или же конкатенацию `'${'.$var.'}'`